# WPF listview virtualization with columns

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, virtualization, recycle

I am trying to create a listview (5'000 items +) that has a smooth scrolling. 
I found a solution in the inet, that "virtualizationmode=Recycling" could do the trick.

Well I totally am lost, since I used a gridview in my old app. 
Now to virtualize the list I can not use gridview anymore, as I read in another post.

How can I bring that to work? I want to bind the items using an observalcollection and I need a Header.

Here is my old listview with gridview:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView_Main" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="18" BorderBrush="#FFE87E00" Foreground="#FFE87E00" Background="Transparent" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="GridView_ListHeader" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                        <!--CheckBox-->
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumn_Check" Width="25" Header=""><GridViewColumn.CellTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel>
                            <!---Tag = Index-->
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Tag="{Binding Index}"/></StackPanel></DataTemplate></GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <!--CheckImage-->
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumn_CheckFake" Width="25" Header=""><GridViewColumn.CellTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel>
                                        <Grid Height="17" Width="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="center">
                                            <Canvas Background="{Binding Color}" Margin="3" Cursor="Hand" Tag="{Binding Index}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_ListIcon_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="Canvas_ListIcon_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Canvas_ListIcon_MouseLeave"><Canvas.OpacityMask>
                                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{Binding ImageCheckbox}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/></Canvas.OpacityMask></Canvas></Grid></StackPanel></DataTemplate></GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <!--Source-->
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumn_Icon"  Header="" Width="25"><GridViewColumn.CellTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel>
                                        <Grid Height="17" Width="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="center">
                                            <Canvas Background="{Binding Color}" Tag="{Binding Index}" Margin="3" MouseEnter="Canvas_SourceIcon_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Canvas_SourceIcon_MouseLeave"><Canvas.OpacityMask>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/></Canvas.OpacityMask></Canvas></Grid></StackPanel></DataTemplate> </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <!--Pos-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Pos" Width="50" Header="Pos"/>
                            <!--Entry-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Entry" Width="200" Header="Eingabe"/>
                        <!--Sap-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SaperionNr}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Sap" Width="100" Header="Saperion"/>
                        <!--Sup-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SupisNr}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Sup" Width="100" Header="Navision"/>
                        <!--Path-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Path" Width="150" Header="Pfad"/>
                        <!--Format-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Format}"  x:Name="GridViewColumn_Format" Width="50" Header="Format"/>
                        <!--Page-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Page}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Page" Width="40" Header="Blatt"/>
                        <!--Stat-->
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" x:Name="GridViewColumn_Stat" Width="175" Header="Status"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listviews should by default have virtualization on. 
There are however case that nullifies their effect.
I would by set a maxheight and ensure that ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" is set.

Comment: hmm, I don't think this is the problem, my listviews height and width are defined by its parent, so I have a fixed size. When I turn "ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" on -> Nothing changes. I activated "ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" to make it at least a little usable. When turning it off it takes about 5 seconds to scroll from element 1 to 1000.

Comment: Well from what I know about virtualization what the parent sets as height and width matters. Humor me and set the Height or even Max Height to something tangible that you can see and try again.

Comment: Thanks...I acctually have a fixed height given from the parent! But You were right! Virtualization is ON by default, and in fact I just realised I can scroll smoothly but I don't know why. I also have removed "ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" but it just works. My Computer must have had not enough ram or something... Thank you

Comment: Magic trigger for me that got virtualization to work was removing or changing ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" to True (from <ListView>)